The router.push function is not working in the login submit handler
I’m using the Next.js App Router and have implemented middleware to check for the presence of an access token. If a user tries to access any page other than the root (/) or login-related pages without a token, I’m adding the returnURL to the search params so they can be redirected back to that page after logging in. However, this approach hasn't been working as expected. For handling the login process, I’m using react-hook-form along with tanstack-query’s useMutation.
const returnURL = useSearchParams().get('returnURL') || '/';

//submit handler
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = () => {
  postSigninMutate(
    { username: payload.username, password: payload.password },
    {
      onSuccess: async (res) => {
        const { response } = res;
        const authorizationToken = response.headers.get('authorization-token');
        const expiresAt = response.headers.get('authorization-token-expired-at');
        const refreshToken = response.headers.get('refresh-token');

        if (authorizationToken && expiresAt && refreshToken) {
          Cookies.set('authorization-token', authorizationToken, { secure: true });
          Cookies.set('expires-at', expiresAt);
          Cookies.set('refresh-token', refreshToken, { secure: true });
        }

        router.push(returnURL);
      },
      onError: (err) => alert(err)
    }
  );
};

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="flex-col-start m-0 w-80 gap-6 pt-10">
...

// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  const accessToken = request.cookies.get('authorization-token');

  console.log(accessToken ? 'yes' : 'no');
  console.log(url);

  if (url === '/') {
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.headers.set('X-Skip-Icons', 'true');
    return response;
  }

  if (
    accessToken &&
    (url === '/signup' ||
      url === '/login' ||
      url === '/kakaoLogin' ||
      url === '/find-password-email' ||
      url === '/find-password-question' ||
      url === '/find-password-newpassword')
  ) {
    if (request.nextUrl.searchParams.has('returnURL')) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('returnURL') || '/', request.url));
    }
    console.log('here');
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }

  if (
    !accessToken &&
    url !== '/signup' &&
    url !== '/login' &&
    url !== '/kakaoLogin' &&
    url !== '/find-password-email' &&
    url !== '/find-password-question' &&
    url !== '/find-password-newpassword'
  ) {
    const redirectURL = new URL('/login', request.url);
    const returnURL = request.nextUrl.pathname + request.nextUrl.search;
    redirectURL.searchParams.set('returnURL', returnURL);

    const response = NextResponse.redirect(redirectURL);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|icons/favicon.ico|icon).*)']
};


I suspected that the issue was due to page caching and a mismatch between cookie updates on the client and server. After calling router.refresh(), the middleware triggered and the page updated, but the URL in the address bar didn’t change. I then added a setTimeout after router.refresh() to delay the router.push(returnURL), and while this solution worked, it made me question whether this is the right approach.
However, when I press the back button, I can still access the login page, which shouldn't happen after a successful login.
router.refresh();
setTimeout(() => {
  router.push(returnURL);
}, 1000);


there's the chance that changing router.push(returnURL); with await router.push(returnURL); will solve part of the issue? the point is that such function is async and returns a promise.. so to ensure everything is in sync (cookies in this case) before anything later gets evaluated, it could be wise to wait for the action to be fully performed

for reference https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/src/shared/lib/router/router.ts push isn't strictly async but it returns this.change that being async returns a promise

Make sure that you have imported useRouter from next/navigation. there are two useRouter in next js

I tried using await, but it didn't resolve the issue. I'm importing useRouter from next/navigation.

To fix the router.push() issue after login:

Use router.replace() instead of router.push() to prevent navigating back to the login page.

router.replace(returnURL);


Refresh the page after setting cookies to ensure middleware is triggered:

await router.refresh();
router.replace(returnURL);


Ensure cookies are set before redirecting to avoid race conditions.

Middleware should properly handle auth:


if (!accessToken && !['/login', '/signup'].includes(url)) {
  const redirectURL = new URL('/login', request.url);
  redirectURL.searchParams.set('returnURL', request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return NextResponse.redirect(redirectURL);
}

This should solve the issue.

Is the await being added to ensure the page refreshes after a cookie is set?
When I add await, I get the message 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression, and the page transition doesn't happen either.

router.replace works as expected. But no page change happens without setTimeout
